# I can't send post by jmeter ,when i connect a ssl vpn client

Tags: jmeter

I can't send post by  jmeter ,when i connect a ssl vpn client,but postman is ok,i do't know why

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWgP3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it shouldn't be any difference, given you're sending the same request you should get the same response.

In order to ensure that JMeter is configured to send the same request as Postman does just record the request (or collection) execution using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html). All you need to do is

1. to configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy

   [image]
2. and to import JMeter's MITM certificate into Postman.

   [image]

See [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling) article for more details.

Depending on your VPN details you might also need to instruct JMeter to use the network interface of the VPN client for sending the requests, it can be done using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

[image]